# c# wpf datagrid content of column disappears when scrolling but re-appears when scrolling back

Tags: c#, wpf, scroll, datagrid

I have a DataGrid which is -90 degree rotated and rows of each columns will be added horizontally. I think this is not difficult to understand.

However, if I scroll down the DataGrid, the content of highest position(Top) starts to disappear one by one as scrolling down but re-appears if I scroll up back to there again.

It seems DataGrid throws the passed-column away and tries to focus on current and next column efficiently for good performance.

I don't want content of columns disappears but all the contents show always as usual.

As a reference, My DataGrid only has 6 columns vertically located on left and each column will only have 1 row horizontally. And the content of some rows are long text with 20~ 30 lines.

Here is my simple code and screenshot.

Please help me with excellent advice. Thank you so much !
(Now, here in Far-East Asia is Mid-Night, so, my comment will be available on tomorrow morning)

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid_Medicineinformation" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="Auto" BorderThickness="0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" UseLayoutRounding="True" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" IsReadOnly="True" RowHeight="NaN" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Collapsed" ColumnWidth="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" EnableColumnVirtualization="True">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="DataGridBase" TargetType="Control">
                <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="-1" />
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="TextOptions.TextFormattingMode" Value="Display" />
            </Style >
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource DataGridBase}"/>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader" BasedOn="{StaticResource DataGridBase}"/>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRowHeader" BasedOn="{StaticResource DataGridBase}"/>

        </DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataGrid.LayoutTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
                <MatrixTransform Matrix="-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0" />
            </TransformGroup>
        </DataGrid.LayoutTransform>
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel.LayoutTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
                            <MatrixTransform Matrix="-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0" />
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </StackPanel.LayoutTransform>
                    <TextBlock Height="100" Text="Binding Image" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataGrid.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect/>
        </DataGrid.Effect>

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding productname}" Header="제품명" Width="Auto">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                        <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
                        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding substancename_korean}" Header="성분명(한글)" Width="Auto">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                        <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
                        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding substancename}" Header="성분명(영문)" Width="Auto">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                        <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
                        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding dosage}" Header="용법 · 용량" Width="Auto">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
                        <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>

                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding efficacy}" Header="효능 · 효과" Width="Auto">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
                        <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>

                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding precautions}" Header="사용상의 주의사항" Width="Auto">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
                        <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My situation consists of 2 matters as horizontal DataGrid and Virtualization.
Somebody provided a solution linked on https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4b95587d-df29-45db-b265-8c3bab77f2a4/c-wpf-virtualization-datagrid-content-of-column-disappears-when-scrolling-but-reappears-when?forum=wpf

I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like problem with the virtualization. Can you try switching virtualization off by setting

```
VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing = "false", VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard" and EnableColumnVirtualization="false"
```

on your datagrid and check if this behaviour stays.

Comment: I also guessed virtualization as performance matter and tried EnableColumnVirtualization = false and EnableRowVirtualization = false and at this morning, followed your solution hopefully. However, the situation is totally same....Oh, do you have better idea? Is there something we are missing?

Comment: The problem is still not solved eventhough I've tried several ways. However, I think there's important point of this problem. As you can see, because the table is -90 degree rotated, the direction of scrolling is vertical but the direction of disappearing is horizontal. When we have normal datagrid table(columns are on Top side), the direction of scrolling(vertical) is same with the direction of additional rows are stacking in the datagrid table. But on this case, the direction of scrolling is vertical but additional rows will be stacking toward right(horizontal).

Comment: Please, do you see some brilliant idea? Excellent idea would be highly appreciated..